# Handle custom view's different touch states

Tags: android, android-listview, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have a custom view, extending `RelativeLayout` and using it as a list item in a `ListView`. It's basically a rectangle with a funky angle on the left. Depending on what I return in my `onTouchEvent`, I can end up in 2 possible states:

1. The list item will display its pressed state properly and return to the unpressed state but will not send the click to the ListView.
2. The list item will remain in the pressed state (and can't get out) BUT will send the click to the ListView perfectly fine.

I have never done custom views of this type before but would really appreciate advice. I assume I'm missing something simple, but I've spent way too much time on this at this point to go on without asking questions!

Here's the code:

```
public class ListItemBackgroundView extends RelativeLayout {
    private final Path PATH = new Path();
    private final Paint BRUSH = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private static int mBackgroundColor = -1;
    private static int mPressedBackgroundColor = -1;
    private static int mAngleOffset = -1;

    private boolean isPressed;

    public ListItemBackgroundView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public ListItemBackgroundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public ListItemBackgroundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final int w = canvas.getWidth();
        final int h = canvas.getHeight();

        if (mBackgroundColor == -1) {
            mBackgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.color_1);
            mPressedBackgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.color_2);
            mAngleOffset = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.list_view_angle_offset);
        }

        PATH.moveTo(0, 0);
        PATH.lineTo(mAngleOffset, h * (0.35f));
        PATH.lineTo(0, h);
        PATH.lineTo(w, h);
        PATH.lineTo(w, 0);
        PATH.lineTo(0, 0);
        PATH.close();

        BRUSH.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        BRUSH.setColor(isPressed ? mPressedBackgroundColor : mBackgroundColor);

        canvas.drawPath(PATH, BRUSH);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean result = super.onTouchEvent(event);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                isPressed = true;
                result = false;
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                isPressed = false;
                result = true;
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried to use a StateListDrawable as a background Drawable?

Comment: @pskink this would work fine if my background was an image and not a custom shape (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: yes, you are missing the fact that SLD displays not Bitmaps but Drawables

Comment: @pskink Ah, I didn't realize you could define them programmatically. I'll give it a shot, though I'm not sure how to create each drawable without onDraw.

Comment: great question! the answer is Drawable.draw

Comment: btw did you use custom SLD (a class that extends SLD) or you used normal SLD and added Drawables via addState ?

Comment: @pskink Check out the answer I put below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a `StateListDrawable` as the background.

```
public class ListItemStateListDrawable extends StateListDrawable {
    private final int mBackgroundColor, mPressedBackgroundColor, mAngleOffset;
    private final Path PATH = new Path();
    private final Paint BRUSH_PRESSED = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Paint BRUSH = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private boolean isDrawn = false;
    private boolean isPressed = false;

    public ListItemStateListDrawable(int backgroundColor, int pressedBackgroundColor, int angleOffset) {
        this.mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.mPressedBackgroundColor = pressedBackgroundColor;
        this.mAngleOffset = angleOffset;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet) {
        for(int st : stateSet){
            boolean pressed = st == android.R.attr.state_pressed;
            boolean not_pressed = st == android.R.attr.stateNotNeeded || st ==  -android.R.attr.state_pressed ||
                    st ==  android.R.attr.state_accelerated || st ==  android.R.attr.state_focused;
            if(pressed || not_pressed){
                isPressed = pressed;
                invalidateSelf();
                break;
            }
        }
        return super.onStateChange(stateSet);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(!isDrawn){
            final int w = canvas.getWidth();
            final int h = canvas.getHeight();

            PATH.moveTo(0, 0);
            PATH.lineTo(mAngleOffset, h * (0.35f));
            PATH.lineTo(0, h);
            PATH.lineTo(w, h);
            PATH.lineTo(w, 0);
            PATH.lineTo(0, 0);
            PATH.close();

            BRUSH.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            BRUSH.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
            BRUSH_PRESSED.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            BRUSH_PRESSED.setColor(mPressedBackgroundColor);

            canvas.drawPath(PATH, BRUSH);
            isDrawn = true;
        }else {
            canvas.drawPath(PATH, isPressed ? BRUSH_PRESSED : BRUSH);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using StateListDrawable and adding the states by addState is a good, std way but you can do it shorter by:

```
class MyStateListDrawable extends StateListDrawable {
    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet) {
        invalidateSelf();
        return super.onStateChange(stateSet);
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int[] state = getState();
        Log.d(TAG, "draw " + StateSet.dump(getState()));
        // remove states you dont want or add you do
        if (isA(android.R.attr.state_pressed)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "draw state_pressed");
            canvas.drawColor(0xffff0000);
        } else
        if (isA(android.R.attr.state_focused)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "draw state_focused");
            canvas.drawColor(0xffff0000);
        } else
        if (isA(android.R.attr.state_selected)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "draw state_selected");
            canvas.drawColor(0xffffff00);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "draw default state");
            canvas.drawColor(0xff0000ff);
        }
    }
    private boolean isA(int i) {
        int[] state = getState();
        for (int st : state) {
            if (st == i) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `canvas.drawColor(color)` removes the shape and fills the rectangle with the color. I've tried doing `canvas.drawPath(PATH, BRUSH)` instead but it only works for the pressed state.

Comment: i used drawColor just to draw anything to be visible and as you can see blue is default state (last else) and red is pressed state (first if), if in problems see logcat since i Log.d the view states

Comment: @kayton you were right: there was a bug, i wrote it in few minutes, now it should work bettet :)